# Add java library to Android Studio project with maven repository

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, android-studio

I want to try this [library](https://github.com/fatshotty/socket.io-java-client) in my android project. I am using **Android Studio 0.4.6**.

The **README.markdown** file tells me to insert this inside **pom.xml**:

```
<!-- in the 'repositories' section -->
<repository>
  <id>keytwo.net</id>
  <name>Keytwo.net Repository</name>
  <url>http://audiobox.keytwo.net</url>
</repository>

<!-- in the 'dependencies' section -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.socket</groupId>
  <artifactId>socket.io-client</artifactId>
  <version>0.2.1</version> <!-- the desidered version -->
</dependency>
```

The problem is that **I do not have any pom.xml**. I created one in my project root directory and synced gradle settings but it does nothing. Till now I only used already compiled .jar files or used the gradle compile function.

How can I use this library in my project?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Android Studio doesn't use Maven as its builder; it uses Gradle instead. Fortunately, Gradle can use Maven repositories to fetch dependencies, so it's a matter of taking that information that would go into the pom file and using it in Gradle format. These modifications go in the **build.gradle** file in your module's directory (not the build file in the project root directory).

First, set up the repository where it can find the dependency.

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://audiobox.keytwo.net' }
}
```

and then add the dependency itself by adding this line to your `dependencies` block:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'io.socket:socket.io-client:0.2.1'
}
```

**Update:**
From POM file:

```
compile '<groupId>:<artifactId>:<version>'
```

Comment: @Scott Barta. So what is the main purpose of Maven inside Android Studio then? In what circumstance Maven is a must option?

Comment: @Halim It doesn't use Maven as a builder but Gradle uses some bits and pieces like being able to download dependencies in its POM format, which is what this refers to.

Comment: Cannot get this to Work. It keeps giving me an build error. Has the solution changed since the beta version? I am using Android Studio version 1.2.1.1 now.

Comment: I wanted to add [this library](https://github.com/agolinko/pdfparse/blob/develop/pom.xml), and it is showing error: Failed to resolve: org.pdfparse:pdfparse:1.0

implementation 'org.pdfparse:pdfparse:1.0'

Comment: Want to add to this - If you copy a maven dependency and paste it directly into Android Studio, it will automatically convert it for you.

Example:
```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Turns into: ` implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'`

Answer (score 5):

Syntax:
implementation 'groupId:artifactId:version'

If this is what you have to import in your Android Studio Project...

```html
// Maven : Add these dependecies to your pom.xml (java6+)
// <dependency>
//     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
//     <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
//     <version>2.8</version>
// </dependency>
// <dependency>
//     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
//     <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
//     <version>2.8</version>
// </dependency>
```

then it translates to this...

```html
implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.8'
implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.8'
```

Comment: Hey @AnuragBhalekar where add these dependencies.