# Duplicate files during packaging of an APK in Android Studio?

Tags: android, maven, twilio

I am trying to use the libraries from Twilio to send SMS but I am having issues importing them to my project. I am following this [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install) and they say to create `pom.xml` and put the following.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
<artifactId>twilio-java-sdk</artifactId>
<version>3.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021970/add-java-library-to-android-studio-project-with-maven-repository) so I followed the answer and converted the dependency to the following and added it to build.gradle

```
compile 'com.twilio.sdk:twilio-java-sdk:3.4.5'
```

Upon compiling I get the following errors, I am not sure how to fix them.

[image]

[image]

Then I decided to use their Pre-built jars so I added them to my dependencies. The built error went away but when I try to send a text message by following the above tutorial, I get the following error when it tries to send it.

```
3-01 21:23:08.056  12507-12507/com.example.ammar.theguardian E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:47)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:93)
            at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioClient.<init>(TwilioClient.java:140)
            at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.<init>(TwilioRestClient.java:19)
            at com.example.ammar.theguardian.guardianService.sendTextMessage(guardianService.java:233)
            at com.example.ammar.theguardian.guardianService.onCreate(guardianService.java:53)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2264)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:127)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:976)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How do I fix the issue ? Thank you!

**Update: build.gradle file contents are posted here as requested in comments**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ammar.theguardian"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.twilio.sdk:twilio-java-sdk:3.4.5'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.2'
}
```

Comment: Add this dependency and try..there seems to exist multiple classes of the same type..`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>`

Comment: I converted it to this `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.2'` and got the same errors but two more warnings about dependency.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file too..

Comment: Remove this line in build.gradle and try....i suspect you have .jar file in libs folder...   `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

Comment: I did but I am still getting the same errors!

Comment: Did you clean your project and rebuilt after removing `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I still got those errors.

Comment: Cant see any other issue..just try removing the line `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1.2'`...let me know what error you are getting after removing this...clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: I removed it and did a clean but I still have the same two errors. What else to try?

Comment: Exhausted all my ideas!!! Best chance to fix it is to create a new project and try

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Evangelist here.

This won't be an issue with twilio itself, but with the fact that you are trying to use the Java library with an Android project.

I know Android is also Java, so in theory it should work :-)

Well, that's not really the case specifically when it comes to making HTTP requests, since Android makes HTTP requests in a slightly different way, and 
`org.apache.httpcomponents` won't simply just work. My recommendation would be to try and use the H[ttpClient for Android](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html), which is a port of `org.apache.httpcomponents` for Android.

It should have all the same namespaces, and adding it to your gradle.build should be a matter of adding the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
}
```

I have not used it myself, but would say this is a good start, and will potentially solve your issue.

Let me know.