# About maven and gradle, how to use them?

Tags: java, android, maven

I need to use a API and as it describe, I could use gradle in android studio, but I didn't see any sentence like " compile'' ". I try to write like "compile 'net.dongliu:apk-parser-2.0.14'". But failed, is it possible change Maven code to gradle?
The  original is below:

Apk-parser has been submited to maven central repo, maven, gradle, ivy and other build tools can be used to get this lib. With maven, you can add apk-parser as dependency by:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.dongliu</groupId>
    <artifactId>apk-parser</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.14</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: gradle has [extensive documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide); have you read it?

Comment: https://github.com/xiaxiaocao/apk-parser

Comment: maven is a quite complex development tool. You should look for some tutorials and documentation and learn it, because "how to use it" is not going to be answered in a few paragraphs. If you only want to use it for just downloading this dependency, usually it will be more useful to just download the .jar from maven central. Come back if you have a more specific question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021970/add-java-library-to-android-studio-project-with-maven-repository I found a similar question

Comment: Yes, I was tried to learn some things about maven, but I failed. I even don't know how to download a .jar maven central. Is there any beginner document about it ?

Comment: Have you tried to read here: https://maven.apache.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try changing

```
compile 'net.dongliu:apk-parser-2.0.14'
```

to

```
compile 'net.dongliu:apk-parser:2.0.14'
```